# How to start the app at specific component?

Tags: angular

Hey guys I`m working on my app with angular and I started to route now ,

how can I HomeComponent to load automatically when I open the site?

Comment: youre probably looking for this: `const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/default', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'default', component: HomeComponent },
];`

Comment: `https://github.com/prabhatmishra33/ShoppingSiteMeanJSApp` Since you started learning It 's a simple angular app repo, you can find the routes file inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a blank route with a pathMatch defined as 'full' to your AppModule (or your AppRoutingModule). It has to be the first route. Afterwards you can add your other routes.

```
import { FirstComponent} from './FirstComponent/FirstComponent.component'

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: FirstComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'agents', loadChildren: () => import('./agents/agents.module').then(m => m.AgentsModule) }
];
```

Comment: You are welcome @Slavix but on stackoverflow you mark the question as solving your problem by checking the V sign :-)